# Unable to install and locate libsqlite3.a

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm a computer science student currently running on Ubuntu 12.10 on VMware player. My assignment requires me to be using sqlite with my c++ program and I have trouble linking it with netbeans. I've read that I need libsqlite3.a to link it with my project.
I have run sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev, however I'm clueless about finding/downloading/making one. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you list files in an installed package:

```
dpkg -L libsqlite3-dev
```

On my (Debian) system, the library is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a`.